# Filter one array of elements using another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit more familiar with python, so what is the javascript equivalent of:

```
In [25]: listA = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]
In [26]: listB = [1,2]
In [27]: intersect = [element for element in listA if element in listB]
In [28]: intersect

Out[28]: [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

This is the closest I can get:

```
var arrA = [1,1,3,4,5,5,6];
var arrB = [1,5];
var arrC = [];
$.each(arrA, function(i,d){ if (arrB.indexOf(d)> -1){arrC.push(d);} ;});
```

Any comments on preferred methods? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements), but it was not exactly what I wanted to answer.

Comment: this one does seem to work, so what the question is?

Comment: I'm new to javascript, just thought I'd see what people have to say.

Comment: If it works and you want to know whether there's something better, you're better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Also, this isn't "pure" JavaScript (`$.each` is from the jQuery library). If you're new to JavaScript don't use jQuery at first. First get used to the language and see what isn't possible in JavaScript, then start to use a library to get rid of the limitations.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Array.filter` like this:

```
var aa = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]
   ,ab = [1,2]
   ,ac = aa.filter(function(a){return ~this.indexOf(a);},ab);
//=> ac is now [1,2,1,1]
```

Or as extension for `Array.prototype`

```
Array.prototype.intersect = function(arr){
 return this.filter(function(a){return ~this.indexOf(a);},arr);
}
// usage
[1,2,3,4,5,1,1].intersect([1,2]); //=> [1,2,1,1]
```

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the `Array.filter` method (also contains a shim for older browsers)

Comment: I didn't catch what `~` do here before `this.indexOf`?

Comment: It's a bit of a trick using the bitwise NOT operator: if `indexOf` == -1 (nothing found), applying the ~-operator makes it `0` and in javascript `0` is falsy . So `~this.indexOf(a)` is shorthand for `this.indexOf(a) !== -1`. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT