# Run time calculation

Tags: runtime

```
Algorithm Mistery (A[1..N])
    for (i <- 1 to N）
    {
        for（i <- 1 to (N-i)）
        {
            if（A[j] > A[j+1])
            {
                temp <- A[i]
                A[j] <- A[j + 1]
                A[i + 1] <- temp
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know please how I calculate the running time of the given code

Comment: We can help you a lot more if, instead of putting an image of your code, you put the actual code in text, so that we can copy and run it ourselves, etc.  Also, you should tell us what programming language you are using, what you've tried, etc. 

Comment: You need to provide your partial solution as well. TYVM.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O runtime for this algorithm would be N^2 since it had the nested for loops.

This post has a similar question: [Run time of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446055/run-time-of-nested-loops)

Check this documentation to figure out how to calculate it yourself. https://www.learneroo.com/modules/106/nodes/559