# How to filter an array from all elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'd like to understand the best way to **filter an array from all elements of another one**. I tried with the filter function, but it doesn't come to me how to give it the values i want to remove. 
 Something Like:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var anotherOne = [2,4];
var filteredArray = array.filter(myCallback);
// filteredArray should now be [1,3]


function myCallBack(){
    return element ! filteredArray; 
    //which clearly can't work since we don't have the reference <,< 
}
```

in case the filter function is not usefull, how would you implement this ?

Edit: i checked the possible duplicate question, and it could be useful for those who understand javascript easily. The answer checked as good makes things easy.

Comment: Pass the other array to filter callback and use `return arrTwo.indexOf(e) === -1;` **Code:** `var filteredArr = firstArr.filter(el => secondArr.indexOf(el) === -1);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.filter() array using another array's elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements)

Comment: are both arrays ordered?

Comment: array are not ordered, also, the second array has a random number of elements.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can use the `this` parameter of the `filter()` function to avoid to store your filter array in a global variable.

```js
var filtered = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(
    function(e) {
      return this.indexOf(e) < 0;
    },
    [2, 4]
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: It works like a charm.
Is it possible to move the function outside and call it in a more understandable way? Like: 
var filtered=[1,2,3,4].filter(myfunct(),[2,4]);

Comment: Sure: var myFunct=function(e){return this.indexOf(e)<0;};
var filtered=[1,2,3,4].filter(myFunct,[2,4]);

Comment: Can this be achieved with lambda expression in ES2016 or TypesScript?

Comment: Angular version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbynpf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: When I use this approach, the second param of filter isn't making it into my function as `this`. `this` always seems to be undefined?! Weird

Comment: @SomethingOn: did you put an array as second parameter?

Comment: I did...the const was already defined before the filter anyway so I was able to reference it regardless.

Comment: If you just add `const a = [2, 4];` at the beginning of the above code, and replace `[2, 4]` by `a` in the filter function, it seems working well. There is probably something else in your code that disturb the process.

Comment: @SunilRaj sory but how is that the angular version. The angular version would deal with streams of data and filter with rxjs

Answer (score 508):

I would do as follows;

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4],
    arr2 = [2,4],
    res = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Rockstar. Thank you, this was incredibly helpful for solving a slightly different problem. Filtering out an array of objects based on an array of values in a react component:

```const filteredResults = this.state.cards.filter(
      result => !this.state.filterOut.includes(result.category)
    )```  where this.state.cards in an array of objects and this.state.filterOut is an array of values that correspond the 'category' key in the objects that I wanted to remove.

Comment: I know, it's an older response, but I simply wanted to let you know that I liked this response a whole lot more and it helped me with one of my problems I had. It is very readable and thus it was easier for me to understand the issue better.

Comment: includes will only work from ES7. If you using ES6 use the accepted solution.

Comment: Arrow functions FTW. Much nicer than the old school callback!

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me a lot and I learned a new paradigm it's great thank you

Answer (score 80):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var anotherOne = [2,4];
var filteredArray = array.filter(myCallBack);

function myCallBack(el){
  return anotherOne.indexOf(el) < 0;
}
```

In the callback, you check if each value of `array` is in `anotherOne`

https://jsfiddle.net/0tsyc1sx/

If you are using `lodash.js`, use `_.difference`

```
filteredArray = _.difference(array, anotherOne);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w8yuvgqn/)

If you have an array of objects :

```
var array = [{id :1, name :"test1"},{id :2, name :"test2"},{id :3, name :"test3"},{id :4, name :"test4"}];

var anotherOne = [{id :2, name :"test2"}, {id :4, name :"test4"}];

var filteredArray  = array.filter(function(array_el){
   return anotherOne.filter(function(anotherOne_el){
      return anotherOne_el.id == array_el.id;
   }).length == 0
});
```

[Demo array of objects](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lh9drm9/5/)

[Demo diff array of objects with lodash](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lh9drm9/6/)

Comment: Hi there can you extend this one in array of objects? i will highly appreciate it

Comment: Are you using lodash ?

Comment: No sir i prefer following the callback method

Comment: well sir it really did work but aside from id how can i filter the otherway with name?

Comment: Hummm...You just have to change `id` in `anotherOne_el.id == array_el.id` with whatever the key you have in your own object. You should get knowledge about arrays and objects in javascript, it will help you to understand better the answer

Comment: @AshBringer `Array of objects` with filter, you deserve bounty for that.

Comment: Points for the `lodash` reference. `lodash` is a dependency of `create-react-app` if you're using react.

Comment: Should be ```.length > 0```

Comment: Consider using  Array.Includes() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 64):

```js
        /* Here's an example that uses (some) ES6 Javascript semantics to filter an object array by another object array. */

        // x = full dataset
        // y = filter dataset
        let x = [
            {"val": 1, "text": "a"},
            {"val": 2, "text": "b"},
            {"val": 3, "text": "c"},
            {"val": 4, "text": "d"},
            {"val": 5, "text": "e"}
            ],
            y = [
            {"val": 1, "text": "a"},
            {"val": 4, "text": "d"}               
            ];

        // Use map to get a simple array of "val" values. Ex: [1,4]
        let yFilter = y.map(itemY => { return itemY.val; });

        // Use filter and "not" includes to filter the full dataset by the filter dataset's val.
        let filteredX = x.filter(itemX => !yFilter.includes(itemX.val));

        // Print the result.
        console.log(filteredX);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how this is working but a little tweaks and it saved the day. Thanks.
it would be very  helpful if someone can explain how this is working

Comment: @ChiragJain let me know what's confusing and I can clarify!

Comment: A wise and logical solution indeed!

Comment: 2 Questions: 

1 did you map the array of objects into a flat array because you need to compare the values?

2 is it possible to do this with .some()

Comment: This one is the best! I also did it without the exclamation mark to find all the values that ARE in the filter array.

Answer (score 31):

If you need to compare an array of objects, this works in all cases:

```
let arr = [{ id: 1, title: "title1" },{ id: 2, title: "title2" }]
let brr = [{ id: 2, title: "title2" },{ id: 3, title: "title3" }]

const res = arr.filter(f => brr.some(item => item.id === f.id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 23):

The code below is the simplest way to filter an array with respect to another array. Both arrays can have objects inside them instead of values.

```js
let array1 = [1, 3, 47, 1, 6, 7];
let array2 = [3, 6];
let filteredArray1 = array1.filter(el => array2.includes(el));
console.log(filteredArray1);
```

Output: `[3, 6]`

Comment: This is not filtering. The output is the array2. Why does this answer have 19 up votes? Doesn't makes sense.

Answer (score 18):

All the above solutions "work", but are less than optimal for performance and are all approach the problem in the same way which is linearly searching all entries at each point using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). A far faster solution (far faster even than a binary search for most cases) would be to sort the arrays and skip ahead as you go along as seen below. However, one downside is that this requires all entries in the array to be numbers or strings. Also however, binary search may in some rare cases be faster than the progressive linear search. These cases arise from the fact that my progressive linear search has a complexity of *O(2n<sub>1</sub>+n<sub>2</sub>)* (only *O(n<sub>1</sub>+n<sub>2</sub>)* in the faster C/C++ version) (where *n<sub>1</sub>* is the searched array and *n<sub>2</sub>* is the filter array), whereas the binary search has a complexity of *O(n<sub>1</sub>ceil(log<sub>2</sub>n<sub>2</sub>))* (ceil = round up -- to the *ceil*ing), and, lastly, the indexOf search has a highly variable complexity between *O(n<sub>1</sub>)* and *O(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>)*, averaging out to *O(n<sub>1</sub>ceil(n<sub>2</sub>÷2))*. Thus, indexOf will only be the fastest, on average, in the cases of *(n<sub>1</sub>,n<sub>2</sub>)* equaling *{1,2}*, *{1,3}*, or *{x,1|x∈N}*. However, this is still not a perfect representation of modern hardware. IndexOf is natively optimized to the fullest extent imaginable in most modern browsers, making it very subject to the laws of [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Thus, if we make the same assumption on indexOf as we do with progressive linear and binary search -- that the array is presorted -- then, according to the stats listed in the link, we can expect roughly a 6x speed up for IndexOf, shifting its complexity to between *O(n<sub>1</sub>÷6)* and *O(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>)*, averaging out to *O(n<sub>1</sub>ceil(n<sub>2</sub>7÷12))*. Finally, take note that the below solution will never work with objects because objects in JavaScript cannot be compared by pointers in JavaScript.

```js
function sortAnyArray(a,b) { return a>b ? 1 : (a===b ? 0 : -1); }
function sortIntArray(a,b) { return (a|0) - (b|0) |0; }
function fastFilter(array, handle) {
    var out=[], value=0;
    for (var i=0,  len=array.length|0; i < len; i=i+1|0)
        if (handle(value = array[i])) 
            out.push( value );
    return out;
}

const Math_clz32 = Math.clz32 || (function(log, LN2){
  return function(x) {
    return 31 - log(x >>> 0) / LN2 | 0; // the "| 0" acts like math.floor
  };
})(Math.log, Math.LN2);

/* USAGE:
  filterArrayByAnotherArray(
      [1,3,5],
      [2,3,4]
  ) yields [1, 5], and it can work with strings too
*/
function filterArrayByAnotherArray(searchArray, filterArray) {
    if (
        // NOTE: This does not check the whole array. But, if you know
        //        that there are only strings or numbers (not a mix of
        //        both) in the array, then this is a safe assumption.
        // Always use `==` with `typeof` because browsers can optimize
        //  the `==` into `===` (ONLY IN THIS CIRCUMSTANCE)
        typeof searchArray[0] == "number" &&
        typeof filterArray[0] == "number" &&
        (searchArray[0]|0) === searchArray[0] &&
        (filterArray[0]|0) === filterArray[0]
    ) {filterArray
        // if all entries in both arrays are integers
        searchArray.sort(sortIntArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortIntArray);
    } else {
        searchArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
    }
    var searchArrayLen = searchArray.length, filterArrayLen = filterArray.length;
    var progressiveLinearComplexity = ((searchArrayLen<<1) + filterArrayLen)>>>0
    var binarySearchComplexity= (searchArrayLen * (32-Math_clz32(filterArrayLen-1)))>>>0;
    // After computing the complexity, we can predict which algorithm will be the fastest
    var i = 0;
    if (progressiveLinearComplexity < binarySearchComplexity) {
        // Progressive Linear Search
        return fastFilter(searchArray, function(currentValue){
            while (filterArray[i] < currentValue) i=i+1|0;
            // +undefined = NaN, which is always false for <, avoiding an infinite loop
            return filterArray[i] !== currentValue;
        });
    } else {
        // Binary Search
        return fastFilter(
            searchArray,
            fastestBinarySearch(filterArray)
        );
    }
}

// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981570/5601591 for implementation
//  details about this binary search algorithm

function fastestBinarySearch(array){
  var initLen = (array.length|0) - 1 |0;
  
  const compGoto = Math_clz32(initLen) & 31;
  return function(sValue) {
    var len = initLen |0;
    switch (compGoto) {
      case 0:
        if (len & 0x80000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0x80000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 1:
        if (len & 0x40000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xc0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 2:
        if (len & 0x20000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xe0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 3:
        if (len & 0x10000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xf0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 4:
        if (len & 0x8000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xf8000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 5:
        if (len & 0x4000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfc000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 6:
        if (len & 0x2000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfe000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 7:
        if (len & 0x1000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xff000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 8:
        if (len & 0x800000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xff800000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 9:
        if (len & 0x400000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffc00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 10:
        if (len & 0x200000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffe00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 11:
        if (len & 0x100000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfff00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 12:
        if (len & 0x80000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfff80000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 13:
        if (len & 0x40000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffc0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 14:
        if (len & 0x20000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffe0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 15:
        if (len & 0x10000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffff0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 16:
        if (len & 0x8000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffff8000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 17:
        if (len & 0x4000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffc000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 18:
        if (len & 0x2000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffe000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 19:
        if (len & 0x1000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffff000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 20:
        if (len & 0x800) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffff800;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 21:
        if (len & 0x400) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffc00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 22:
        if (len & 0x200) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffe00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 23:
        if (len & 0x100) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffff00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 24:
        if (len & 0x80) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffff80;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 25:
        if (len & 0x40) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffc0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 26:
        if (len & 0x20) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffe0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 27:
        if (len & 0x10) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffff0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 28:
        if (len & 0x8) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffff8;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 29:
        if (len & 0x4) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffffc;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 30:
        if (len & 0x2) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffffe;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 31:
        if (len & 0x1) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffff;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
    }
    // MODIFICATION: Instead of returning the index, this binary search
    //                instead returns whether something was found or not.
    if (array[len|0] !== sValue) {
       return true; // preserve the value at this index
    } else {
       return false; // eliminate the value at this index
    }
  };
}
```

<sup>Please see my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981570/560159) for more details on the binary search algorithm used</sup>

If you are squeamish about file size (which I respect), then you can sacrifice a little performance in order to greatly reduce the file size and increase maintainability.

```js
function sortAnyArray(a,b) { return a>b ? 1 : (a===b ? 0 : -1); }
function sortIntArray(a,b) { return (a|0) - (b|0) |0; }
function fastFilter(array, handle) {
    var out=[], value=0;
    for (var i=0,  len=array.length|0; i < len; i=i+1|0)
        if (handle(value = array[i])) 
            out.push( value );
    return out;
}

/* USAGE:
  filterArrayByAnotherArray(
      [1,3,5],
      [2,3,4]
  ) yields [1, 5], and it can work with strings too
*/
function filterArrayByAnotherArray(searchArray, filterArray) {
    if (
        // NOTE: This does not check the whole array. But, if you know
        //        that there are only strings or numbers (not a mix of
        //        both) in the array, then this is a safe assumption.
        typeof searchArray[0] == "number" &&
        typeof filterArray[0] == "number" &&
        (searchArray[0]|0) === searchArray[0] &&
        (filterArray[0]|0) === filterArray[0]
    ) {
        // if all entries in both arrays are integers
        searchArray.sort(sortIntArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortIntArray);
    } else {
        searchArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
    }
    // Progressive Linear Search
    var i = 0;
    return fastFilter(searchArray, function(currentValue){
        while (filterArray[i] < currentValue) i=i+1|0;
        // +undefined = NaN, which is always false for <, avoiding an infinite loop
        return filterArray[i] !== currentValue;
    });
}
```

To prove the difference in speed, let us examine some JSPerfs. For [filtering an array of 16 elements](https://jsperf.com/filtering-one-array-by-another-array-x16/1), binary search is roughly 17% faster than indexOf while filterArrayByAnotherArray is roughly 93% faster than indexOf. For [filtering an array of 256 elements](https://jsperf.com/filtering-one-array-by-another-array-x256/1), binary search is roughly 291% faster than indexOf while filterArrayByAnotherArray is roughly 353% faster than indexOf. For [filtering an array of 4096 elements](https://jsperf.com/filtering-one-array-by-another-array-x4096/1), binary search is roughly 2655% faster than indexOf while filterArrayByAnotherArray is roughly 4627% faster than indexOf.

## Reverse-filtering (like an AND gate)

The previous section provided code to take array A and array B, and remove all elements from A that exist in B:

```js
filterArrayByAnotherArray(
    [1,3,5],
    [2,3,4]
);
// yields [1, 5]
```

This next section will provide code for reverse-filtering, where we remove all elements from A that DO NOT exist in B. This process is functionally equivalent to only retaining the elements common to both A and B, like an AND gate:

```js
reverseFilterArrayByAnotherArray(
    [1,3,5],
    [2,3,4]
);
// yields [3]
```

Here is the code for reverse filtering:

```js
function sortAnyArray(a,b) { return a>b ? 1 : (a===b ? 0 : -1); }
function sortIntArray(a,b) { return (a|0) - (b|0) |0; }
function fastFilter(array, handle) {
    var out=[], value=0;
    for (var i=0,  len=array.length|0; i < len; i=i+1|0)
        if (handle(value = array[i])) 
            out.push( value );
    return out;
}

const Math_clz32 = Math.clz32 || (function(log, LN2){
  return function(x) {
    return 31 - log(x >>> 0) / LN2 | 0; // the "| 0" acts like math.floor
  };
})(Math.log, Math.LN2);

/* USAGE:
  reverseFilterArrayByAnotherArray(
      [1,3,5],
      [2,3,4]
  ) yields [3], and it can work with strings too
*/
function reverseFilterArrayByAnotherArray(searchArray, filterArray) {
    if (
        // NOTE: This does not check the whole array. But, if you know
        //        that there are only strings or numbers (not a mix of
        //        both) in the array, then this is a safe assumption.
        // Always use `==` with `typeof` because browsers can optimize
        //  the `==` into `===` (ONLY IN THIS CIRCUMSTANCE)
        typeof searchArray[0] == "number" &&
        typeof filterArray[0] == "number" &&
        (searchArray[0]|0) === searchArray[0] &&
        (filterArray[0]|0) === filterArray[0]
    ) {
        // if all entries in both arrays are integers
        searchArray.sort(sortIntArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortIntArray);
    } else {
        searchArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
    }
    var searchArrayLen = searchArray.length, filterArrayLen = filterArray.length;
    var progressiveLinearComplexity = ((searchArrayLen<<1) + filterArrayLen)>>>0
    var binarySearchComplexity= (searchArrayLen * (32-Math_clz32(filterArrayLen-1)))>>>0;
    // After computing the complexity, we can predict which algorithm will be the fastest
    var i = 0;
    if (progressiveLinearComplexity < binarySearchComplexity) {
        // Progressive Linear Search
        return fastFilter(searchArray, function(currentValue){
            while (filterArray[i] < currentValue) i=i+1|0;
            // +undefined = NaN, which is always false for <, avoiding an infinite loop
            // For reverse filterning, I changed !== to ===
            return filterArray[i] === currentValue;
        });
    } else {
        // Binary Search
        return fastFilter(
            searchArray,
            inverseFastestBinarySearch(filterArray)
        );
    }
}

// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981570/5601591 for implementation
//  details about this binary search algorithim

function inverseFastestBinarySearch(array){
  var initLen = (array.length|0) - 1 |0;
  
  const compGoto = Math_clz32(initLen) & 31;
  return function(sValue) {
    var len = initLen |0;
    switch (compGoto) {
      case 0:
        if (len & 0x80000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0x80000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 1:
        if (len & 0x40000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xc0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 2:
        if (len & 0x20000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xe0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 3:
        if (len & 0x10000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xf0000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 4:
        if (len & 0x8000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xf8000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 5:
        if (len & 0x4000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfc000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 6:
        if (len & 0x2000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfe000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 7:
        if (len & 0x1000000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xff000000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 8:
        if (len & 0x800000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xff800000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 9:
        if (len & 0x400000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffc00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 10:
        if (len & 0x200000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffe00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 11:
        if (len & 0x100000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfff00000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 12:
        if (len & 0x80000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfff80000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 13:
        if (len & 0x40000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffc0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 14:
        if (len & 0x20000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffe0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 15:
        if (len & 0x10000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffff0000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 16:
        if (len & 0x8000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffff8000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 17:
        if (len & 0x4000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffc000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 18:
        if (len & 0x2000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffe000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 19:
        if (len & 0x1000) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffff000;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 20:
        if (len & 0x800) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffff800;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 21:
        if (len & 0x400) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffc00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 22:
        if (len & 0x200) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffe00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 23:
        if (len & 0x100) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffff00;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 24:
        if (len & 0x80) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffff80;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 25:
        if (len & 0x40) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffc0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 26:
        if (len & 0x20) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffe0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 27:
        if (len & 0x10) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffff0;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 28:
        if (len & 0x8) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffff8;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 29:
        if (len & 0x4) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffffc;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 30:
        if (len & 0x2) {
          const nCB = len & 0xfffffffe;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
      case 31:
        if (len & 0x1) {
          const nCB = len & 0xffffffff;
          len ^= (len ^ (nCB-1)) & ((array[nCB] <= sValue |0) - 1 >>>0);
        }
    }
    // MODIFICATION: Instead of returning the index, this binary search
    //                instead returns whether something was found or not.
    // For reverse filterning, I swapped true with false and vice-versa
    if (array[len|0] !== sValue) {
       return false; // preserve the value at this index
    } else {
       return true; // eliminate the value at this index
    }
  };
}
```

For the slower smaller version of the reverse filtering code, see below.

```js
function sortAnyArray(a,b) { return a>b ? 1 : (a===b ? 0 : -1); }
function sortIntArray(a,b) { return (a|0) - (b|0) |0; }
function fastFilter(array, handle) {
    var out=[], value=0;
    for (var i=0,  len=array.length|0; i < len; i=i+1|0)
        if (handle(value = array[i])) 
            out.push( value );
    return out;
}

/* USAGE:
  reverseFilterArrayByAnotherArray(
      [1,3,5],
      [2,3,4]
  ) yields [3], and it can work with strings too
*/
function reverseFilterArrayByAnotherArray(searchArray, filterArray) {
    if (
        // NOTE: This does not check the whole array. But, if you know
        //        that there are only strings or numbers (not a mix of
        //        both) in the array, then this is a safe assumption.
        typeof searchArray[0] == "number" &&
        typeof filterArray[0] == "number" &&
        (searchArray[0]|0) === searchArray[0] &&
        (filterArray[0]|0) === filterArray[0]
    ) {
        // if all entries in both arrays are integers
        searchArray.sort(sortIntArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortIntArray);
    } else {
        searchArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
        filterArray.sort(sortAnyArray);
    }
    // Progressive Linear Search
    var i = 0;
    return fastFilter(searchArray, function(currentValue){
        while (filterArray[i] < currentValue) i=i+1|0;
        // +undefined = NaN, which is always false for <, avoiding an infinite loop
        // For reverse filter, I changed !== to ===
        return filterArray[i] === currentValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sure will be helpful for someone sooner or later, even if it should be used in edge cases (I.E. only when a performance problems raise up).
In all other cases i'd suggest to use the maintainable / readable version.

Comment: @koop4 This version is just as readable -- all you need to do is add in a few comments explaining that this method filters an array from all elements of another array. Also, extra performance never hurts (in fact, I would say it is good). Nevertheless, I do definitely agree that because this version is more complex, it is less maintainable than other solutions.

Comment: @JackGiffin I think by readable he means mantainable and fast to read and understand by the average web developer, for when a change or simple understaning is needed. Great solution, just not for most cases.

Comment: @zardilior  Thank you for your input. I do indeed have a single-minded obsession with performance and it does indeed get in the way of my projects. I have tried to improve myself, but, alas, my obsession sometimes gets the better of me. Thank you for understanding and thank you for explaining your concern so clearly.

Comment: @JackGiffin early optimization is one of the worst things for projects, performance should be applied generally in to ways, writing efficient code, if simple enough, meaning dont write straight through bad code, and when optimization is needed because performance doesn't meets requirements. So a person like you should work optimizing other projects that need that obsession derived skill. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @zardilior It really does help. Thank you so much for your advice zardilior. I shall take it to heart and act upon it.

Comment: @JackGiffin glad to be of service

Comment: How does it will work if I'm trying to filter array by **not in** other array?

Comment: @GermanAlzate Excellent point. I added a new section to address that use case.

Comment: @JackGiffin its great! but I it does looks like an 'intersection'. I was looking for some like remove all entries in array a that exists in array b: `diff([1, 2, 3], [3,4,5]) => [1,2]`

Comment: @GermanAlzate Please see my top original answer snippets: `filterArrayByAnotherArray([1,2,3], [3,4,5])` yields `[1,2]`.

Answer (score 9):

There are many answers for your question, but I don't see anyone using lambda expresion:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var anotherOne = [2,4];
var filteredArray = array.filter(x => anotherOne.indexOf(x) < 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

with object filter result

```
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}].filter(v=>!([{id:2},{id:4}].some(e=>e.id === v.id)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it when the items in the arrays are objects.

The idea is to find the array of only the keys in an inner array using the map function

Then check if the array of those keys contain a specific element key in the outer array.

```
const existsInBothArrays = array1.filter((element1) =>
    array2.map((element2) => element2._searchKey).includes(element1._searchKey),
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

The OA can also be implemented in ES6 as follows

ES6:

```
 const filtered = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(e => {
    return this.indexOf(e) < 0;
  },[2, 4]);
```

Comment: Outside of the arrow syntax, what ES6 advantage does this solution have as far as filtering?

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example

```js
let firstArray=[1,2,3,4,5];
let secondArray=[2,3];  
let filteredArray = firstArray.filter((a) => secondArray.indexOf(a)<0);
console.log(filteredArray); //above line gives [1,4,5]
```

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the type of array.

For simple arrays like arrays of strings. You can use the code as follows just like @Redu and @Hugolpz pointed out

```
 var arr1 = [1,2,3,4],
        arr2 = [2,4],
        res = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item));
    console.log(res);
```

Then for more complex array filters like filtering an array of objects from another array of object, you can use the code bellow

```
function filterArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(item1 => !arr2.some(item2 => item1.id === item2.id));
}
```

OR

```
function filterArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr2.map(item => item.id));
  return arr1.reduce((filtered, item) => {
    if (!set.has(item.id)) {
      filtered.push(item);
    }
    return filtered;
  }, []);
}
```

Both of these methods are efficient and should work well even with large arrays. However, in case you have a huge amount of data, using a more performant data structure like Map or HashSet could be more optimal.

Map

```
function filterArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const map = new Map(arr2.map(item => [item.id, item]));
  return arr1.filter(item => !map.has(item.id));
}
```

Hashset

```
function filterArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr2.map(item => item.id));
  return arr1.filter(item => !set.has(item.id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the filter function to iterate over the "filter array".

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5, 6, 7];
var filter = [4, 5, 6];

var filtered = arr.filter(
  function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
      if (val == filter[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter and then for the filter function use a reduction of the filtering array which checks and returns true when it finds a match then invert on return (!).  The filter function is called once per element in the array.  You are not doing a comparison of any of the elements in the function in your post.

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  a2 = [2, 3];

var filtered = a1.filter(function(x) {
  return !a2.reduce(function(y, z) {
    return x == y || x == z || y == true;
  })
});

document.write(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr1= [1,2,3,4];
var arr2=[2,4]

function fil(value){
return value !=arr2[0] &&  value != arr2[1]
}

document.getElementById("p").innerHTML= arr1.filter(fil)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it work, but i'd prefer to keep the local scope. Also the arr2 has a random number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function arr(arr1,arr2){
  
  function filt(value){
    return arr2.indexOf(value) === -1;
    }
  
  return arr1.filter(filt)
  }

document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = arr([1,2,3,4],[2,4])
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible filtering array from another array which contain object properties

```js
function filterFn(array, diffArray, prop, propDiff) {
    diffArray = !propDiff ? diffArray : diffArray.map(d => d[propDiff])
    this.fn = f => diffArray.indexOf(f) === -1
    if (prop) {
         return array.map(r => r[prop]).filter(this.fn)
    } else {
         return array.filter(this.fn)
    }
}

//You can use it like this;

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.index = i
    obj.value = Math.pow(2, i)
    arr.push(obj)
}

var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var sec = [{t:2}, {t:99}, {t:256}, {t:4096}]

var log = console.log.bind(console)

var filtered = filterFn(arr, sec, 'value', 't')

var filtered2 = filterFn(arr2, sec, null, 't')

log(filtered, filtered2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic filterByIndex() function and make use of type inference in TS to save the hassle with the callback function:

let's say you have your array [1,2,3,4] that you want to filter() with the indices specified in the [2,4] array.

```
var filtered = [1,2,3,4,].filter(byIndex(element => element, [2,4]))
```

the byIndex function expects the element function and an array and looks like this:

```
byIndex = (getter: (e:number) => number, arr: number[]) => (x: number) => {
    var i = getter(x);
    return arr.indexOf(i); 
}
```

result is then

```
filtered = [1,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following examples use `new Set()` to create a filtered array that has only unique elements:

Array with primitive data types: string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = [3, 4, 5];
const c = Array.from(new Set(a.concat(b)));
```

Array with objects as items:

```
const a = [{id:1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const b = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];
const stringifyObject = o => JSON.stringify(o);
const parseString = s => JSON.parse(s);
const c = Array.from(new Set(a.concat(b).map(stringifyObject)), parseString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Jack Giffin is great but doesn't work for arrays with numbers bigger than 2^32. Below is a refactored, fast version to filter an array based on Jack's solution but it works for 64-bit arrays.

```
const Math_clz32 = Math.clz32 || ((log, LN2) => x => 31 - log(x >>> 0) / LN2 | 0)(Math.log, Math.LN2);

const filterArrayByAnotherArray = (searchArray, filterArray) => {

    searchArray.sort((a,b) => a > b);
    filterArray.sort((a,b) => a > b);

    let searchArrayLen = searchArray.length, filterArrayLen = filterArray.length;
    let progressiveLinearComplexity = ((searchArrayLen<<1) + filterArrayLen)>>>0
    let binarySearchComplexity = (searchArrayLen * (32-Math_clz32(filterArrayLen-1)))>>>0;

    let i = 0;

    if (progressiveLinearComplexity < binarySearchComplexity) {
      return searchArray.filter(currentValue => {
        while (filterArray[i] < currentValue) i=i+1|0;
        return filterArray[i] !== currentValue;
      });
    }
    else return searchArray.filter(e => binarySearch(filterArray, e) === null);
}

const binarySearch = (sortedArray, elToFind) => {
  let lowIndex = 0;
  let highIndex = sortedArray.length - 1;
  while (lowIndex <= highIndex) {
    let midIndex = Math.floor((lowIndex + highIndex) / 2);
    if (sortedArray[midIndex] == elToFind) return midIndex; 
    else if (sortedArray[midIndex] < elToFind) lowIndex = midIndex + 1;
    else highIndex = midIndex - 1;
  } return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give you an additional solution...

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
const arr2 = [2,4];
const container = arr2.reduce((res,item) => {
 res[item] = true;
 return res;
}, {});
const result = arr1.filter(item => !container[item]);
```

About the time complexity of above code: O(n).
And,... we'll need more spaces (space complexity O(n)) => Trade-off... :))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter an array with different structures with some matching properties you should do it like this.

```
let filteredArray = [];

array1.map(array1Item => {
array2.map(array2Item => {
  if (array1.property1 === array2.property2) {
    filteredArray.push(array1Item);
  }
});
```

this should make your life easy!

Answer (score -3):

The best description to `filter` function is https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter

You should simply condition function:

```
function conditionFun(element, index, array) {
   return element >= 10;
}
filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(conditionFun);
```

And you can't access the variable value before it is assigned

Comment: This answer only uses one array.