# How can I create a new object that only contains the key/value pairs specified in an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a function an array of keys and an object, and return a new object that only contains the key/value pairs that I specify in the keys array.

So if I had an object like this:

```
{"name" : "John Smith", "position" : "CEO", "year" : "2019" }
```

And I passed the array

```
["name", "year"]
```

the new object returned would be:

```
{"name" : "John Smith", "year" : "2019" }
```

I've been playing around with it, but my code is not working.

```
function parse(keys, data) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data);

    let newObj = {};

    keys.array.forEach(element => {
        newObj[element] = obj.element;
    });

    return newObj;
};
```

Comment: Please read the description of the `json` tag. This question is not about JSON, but about a JavaScript object. That it is the result of applying `JSON.parse` is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the tag.

Comment: I also removed the word from your question. You can just say "object" instead of the misleading "JSON object". JSON is a text format.

Comment: `obj.element;` should be `obj[element]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to do `parse`.Secondly this line `keys.array.forEach` is wrong. This is because there is no `array` key inside `keys`.Also replace `obj.element;` with `data[element]`

```js
let data = {
  "name": "John Smith",
  "position": "CEO",
  "year": "2019"
}
let keys = ["name", "year"]


function parse(keys, data) {
  let newJson = {};
  keys.forEach(element => {
    newJson[element] = data[element];
  });

  return newJson;
};

console.log(parse(keys, data))
```

Comment: i like this  nice

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be through filtering an array of object entries:

```
const entries = Object.entries({
  "name" : "John Smith",
  "position" : "CEO",
  "year" : "2019"
})
```

`entries` contains:

```
[
  [
    "name",
    "John Smith"
  ],
  [
    "position",
    "CEO"
  ],
  [
    "year",
    "2019"
  ]
]
```

Filtering out keys:

```
const filteredEntries = entries.filter(([ key ]) => ["name", "year"].includes(key))
```

`filteredEntries` contains:

```
[
  [
    "name",
    "John Smith"
  ],
  [
    "year",
    "2019"
  ]
]
```

Last step - construct an object:

```
const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries)
```

`filteredObject` contains:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "year": "2019"
}
```

Putting it together as a function:

```
function filterObjectByGivenKeys(object, keys) {
  const filteredEntries = Object
    .entries(object)
    .filter(([ key ]) => keys.includes(key))

  return Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries)
}
```

Or, if we prefer `reduce` and more terse syntax:

```
const filterObjectByGivenKeys = (object, keys) =>
  Object.entries(object)
    .filter(([ key ]) => keys.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }), {})
```

Comment: Actually, an one-liner `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(e => keys.includes(e[0])))`

Answer (score 2):

The correct (e.g., lazy) way to accomplish this would to use `lodash`, because code you don't write is code you don't have to maintain:

```
const pick = require('lodash.pick');

const obj = {
    name     : 'John Smith' ,
    position : 'CEO' ,
    year     : '2019',
};
const desired = [ 'name', 'year' ];

const filtered = pick(obj, desired );
```

If you want to roll your own, something like this should do the trick:

```
function filter_obj(obj = {}, keys = [] ) {
    if ( !keys || !keys.length ) return obj;

    const desired = new Set(keys);
    const filtered = {};
    for ( [ key, value ] of Object.entries(obj) ) {
        if ( !desired.has(key) ) continue;
        filtered[key] = value;
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is close.

Maybe try:

```
newObj[element] = obj[element];
```

instead of

```
newObj[element] = obj.element
```

That way you will use the variable `element` instead of trying to look up the key "element" which will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using for in to loop object keys

1. Loop keys by for in
2. Check key with the filtered keys
3. Add to new object

```js
var obj = {"name" : "John Smith", "position" : "CEO", "year" : "2019" }
var fil = ["name", "year"]
var result = {}
for(let key in obj){
  if(fil.indexOf(key) !==-1){
    result[key] = obj[key]
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the reduce method:

```js
var input = {"name" : "John Smith", "position" : "CEO", "year" : "2019" };
var properties = ["name", "year"];

function getNewObject(json, props) {
  // Get all object properties
  var availableProperties = Object.keys(json);

  // Loop through the requested properties and return the object
  return props.reduce((pv, cv) => {
    // Check if the property exists on the object
    if(availableProperties.includes(cv)){
      pv[cv] = json[cv]
    }
    return pv;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getNewObject(input, properties));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the object parsing you had above since your object isn't stringified... If it was stringified the "" would be wrapping the entire object... in production you can simple add in the parsing if needed.

```
function parse(keys, data) {
   let newObj = {};

   for (const dataKey in data){
       for (let i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (data.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
               newObj[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
           }
       }
   }

   return newObj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you do that using `filter` and Object `entries` or you can also use `reduce`.

```js
const person = {
  "name": "John Smith",
  "position": "CEO",
  "year": "2019",
  "job": "front-end"
};

const formatObject = (arr, o) => {
  let finalObject = {};

  Object.entries(o).filter(([key, value]) => {
    if (arr.includes(key)) {
      finalObject = {
        ...finalObject,
        [key]: value
      }
    }

  });

  return finalObject;

}


console.log(formatObject(["name", "year", "job"], person))
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this line {"name" : "John Smith", "position" : "CEO", "year" : "2019" } inside single quotation, or you don't need to use JSON.parse:

```
'{"name" : "John Smith", "position" : "CEO", "year" : "2019" }'
```

Then you don't need the array, only keys, keys.**array**.forEach.
And obj[element]:

```
  keys.forEach(element => {
    newObj[element] = obj[element];
  });
```