# Return a subset of an array of objects that matches a property of an another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

inputs:

```
const parentArray = [
{id:1, name:'foo'},
{id:2, name:'bar'},
{id:4, name:'foobar'},
{id:6, name:'barfoo'}
]

const childArray = [
  {parent_id:1, prop:'prop1'}, 
  {parent_id:2, prop:'prop2'}, 
  {parent_id:3, prop:'prop3'},
  {parent_id:4, prop:'prop4'},
  {parent_id:5, prop:'prop5'}
];
```

output:

```
const resultingArray = [
{id:1, name:'foo'},
{id:2, name:'bar'},
{id:4, name:'foobar'}
]
```

I want to compare the properties `id` and `parent_id` from both arrays and return a subset of `parentArray` for the matching properties

I've tried to filter them out but not having success, using lodash

Comment: the answers here might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977985/filter-out-an-array-from-the-duplicates-in-another-array?noredirect=1#comment102365921_57977985

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just edited the question for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with a combination of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in the following way.

```
const resultingArray = parentArray
                       .filter(x => childArray.some( y => y.parent_id===x.id));
```

Check [this JS bin](https://jsbin.com/kerewaxasi/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the wanted parents and filter the `parent` array.

```js
var parents = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }],
    children = [{ parent_id: 1, prop: 'prop1' }, { parent_id: 3, prop: 'prop3' }],
    wanted = new Set(children.map(({ parent_id }) => parent_id)),
    result = parents.filter(({ id }) => wanted.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `Set` as a lookup table for the `parent_id` data from the child and then use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter through the parent entries and use `Set#has` to check if the id is contained in the `Set`:

```js
const parentArray = [{id:1, name:'foo'},{id:2, name:'bar'}, {id:4, name:'foo'},{id:6, name:'bar'}]

const childArray = [
  {parent_id:1, prop:'prop1'}, 
  {parent_id:2, prop:'prop2'}, 
  {parent_id:3, prop:'prop3'},
  {parent_id:4, prop:'prop4'},
  {parent_id:5, prop:'prop5'}
];

function findSubSet(){
  const lookup = new Set(childArray.map(({parent_id}) => parent_id));
  return parentArray.filter(p => lookup.has(p.id));
}
console.log(findSubSet(parentArray, childArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` & `findIndex`. In the reduce callback use `findIndex` to check if there exist same id.If `id` exist it will return the `index` & if not then it will return `-1`. So if index is not -1 then you can push the value to accumulator(acc)

```js
const parentArray = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bar'
}]

const childArray = [{
    parent_id: 1,
    prop: 'prop1'
  },
  {
    parent_id: 2,
    prop: 'prop2'
  },
  {
    parent_id: 3,
    prop: 'prop3'
  }
]

let filteredData = parentArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let getIndexFromChild = childArray.findIndex(function(item) {
    return curr.id === item.parent_id
  });

  if (getIndexFromChild !== -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, your example is unclear, but filtering an array using another array, assuming you want to use the properties `id` from `parentArray` and `parent_id` from `childArray`, then I would use this:

```
resultingArray = childArray.filter(c=> parentArray.find(p => p.id === c.parentId);
```

Comment: Ok, then Vandesh's reply probably is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get the matching values:

```js
const parentArray = [{id:1, name:'foo'},{id:2, name:'bar'}]

const childArray = [
  {parent_id:1, prop:'prop1'}, 
  {parent_id:3, prop:'prop3'}
]

let result = parentArray.filter(i => childArray.some(j => j.parent_id == i.id))

console.log(result)
```