# How to filter an array with elements of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of strings that I want to filter by another array of words.
The goal is to remove the entire string if it contains one word of the second argument.

Let's take this as an **example** :

```
comments = [ "Very useful tutorial, thank you so much!",
  "React is not a damn framework, it's a LIBRARY"
  "Why you put bloody kitten pictures in a tech tutorial is beyond me!",
  "Which one is better, React or Angular?",
  'There is no "better", it depends on your use case, DAMN YOU'
]

bannedWords = ['bloody', 'damn']
```

My code is returning the full array of `comments`, I don't understand how I can filter through all the elements of the `bannedWords` array.
I'm pretty sure I'm lacking of a basic thing right there but I'm stuck for a while now so... Thanks !

Here is what I coded :

```
  return comments.filter(comment => comment.includes(bannedWords) == false)
};
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/) (by the founder of StackOverflow itself)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: Did you research this?  There are PLENTY of other answers to almost the same exact here on StackOverflow.  Nobody should even be answering this question, everybody should be marking it as a duplicate

Comment: Your problem is here `comment.includes(bannedWords)` here you're passing complete array as `parameter` to `includes` where as you need to match pass individual name at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `.every` of the banned words are not included in the comment you're iterating over. Make sure to call `toLowerCase` on the comment first:

```js
const comments = ["Very useful tutorial, thank you so much!", "React is not a damn framework, it's a LIBRARY",
  "Why you put bloody kitten pictures in a tech tutorial is beyond me!", "Which one is better, React or Angular?", 'There is no "better", it depends on your use case, DAMN YOU'];
const bannedWords = ['bloody', 'damn'];

const result = comments.filter(comment => bannedWords.every(word => !comment.toLowerCase().includes(word)))
console.log(result);
```

Or, if you want to construct a regular expression:

```js
const comments = ["Very useful tutorial, thank you so much!", "React is not a damn framework, it's a LIBRARY",
  "Why you put bloody kitten pictures in a tech tutorial is beyond me!", "Which one is better, React or Angular?", 'There is no "better", it depends on your use case, DAMN YOU'];
const bannedWords = ['bloody', 'damn'];
const re = new RegExp(bannedWords.join('|'), 'i');

const result = comments.filter(comment => !re.test(comment));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function filterOffensiveComments(comments, bannedWords) {
  return comments.filter(comment => !bannedWords.some(word => comment.includes(word)));
}
```

`.includes` only accepts a single `String`.
Use `some`, not `every`, because it will early-return.

Comment: code only aren't considered as  good answer,
Please add explanation why OP's code wasn't working why yours works.

Comment: @Code Maniac answer.`includes`( explanation ) === `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterOffensiveComments(comments, bannedWords) {
  return comments.filter(item=>{
    let shouldDelete = false;
    bannedWords.forEach(word=>{
        if(item.includes(word)){
            shouldDelete = true;
        }
    })
    if(shouldDelete){
        return null
    }
    return item;
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to implement using callback -

```
const comments = [ "Very useful tutorial, thank you so much!",
  "React is not a damn framework, it's a LIBRARY",
  "Why you put bloody kitten pictures in a tech, tutorial is beyond me!",
  "Which one is better, React or Angular?",
  'There is no "better", it depends on your use case, DAMN YOU'
];

const bannedWords = ['bloody', 'damn'];

function getFilteredResults(item, index, array){
var flag = 0;
bannedWords.forEach(bannedWord => {
if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(bannedWord.toLowerCase()) != -1)
    flag = 1;
});
return flag == 0;
}

comments.filter(getFilteredResults);
```