# Filtering array A based on whether it contains any or partial elements from array B

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, array A has a list of elements that may or may not contains an element from array B. I want to filter array A so that it only contains elements where it contains at least one element from array B.

```
const a = [
  'cqAWS1x2', 
  'cqAM1c',
  'cqA10a + cqA10b',
  'cqA10axZAF + cqA10bxZAF']

const b = [
  'cqAWS1x2',
  'cqA10a',
  'cqA10axZAF']
```

I want to filter a so it'll be

```
 ['cqAWS1x2',
  'cqA10a + cqA10b',
  'cqA10axZAF + cqA10bxZAF']
```

`'cqAWS1x2'` because Array b contains that element, `'cqA10a + cqA10b'` because b contains 'cqA10a' which is part of `'cqA10a + cqA10b'`. Same for `'cqA10axZAF + cqA10bxZAF'`, because b contains 'cqA10axZAF'.

This is what I have so far:

```
a.filter(avc => b.some(bvc => bvc.includes(avc)))
```

In the result, I get only ['cqAWS1x2'] but not `'cqA10a + cqA10b'` and `'cqA10axZAF + cqA10bxZAF'`.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Close @HereticMonkey, but it was the `some()` and `String#includes()` that was tripping the OP up.

Comment: @pilchard Take your pick: [How to filter an array with elements of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58163330/215552), [How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5582574/215552), [Check if a string contains any element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37428338/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch the `avc` and `bvc` in your `includes()` call (`avc` is the longer string, check if it includes the shorter `bvc`).

```js
const a = ['cqAWS1x2', 'cqAM1c', 'cqA10a + cqA10b', 'cqA10axZAF + cqA10bxZAF'];
const b = ['cqAWS1x2', 'cqA10a', 'cqA10axZAF'];

console.log(a.filter((avc) => b.some((bvc) => avc.includes(bvc))));
```