# How to generate random numbers from an array excluding some given numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a game whereby the player selects 6 numbers between 1 - 36.
What I want to do is to make a new array that excludes the 6 selected numbers and the new array will be 30 in length.

Here is what I've done.
The first array generated:

```
var selectedBalls = [2, 8, 25, 13, 8, 5]; //take this as the selected balls for example
var totalBalls = [];

function getBallsReady(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
    totalBalls.push(i);
  }
}
```

Here is the code I tried to get the new array, but is not perfect yet because at least 1 or 2 number(s) from the selected 6 numbers is still always part of the new array.

```
function generateNewBalls() {
  let clonedTotalBalls = [...totalBalls];

  selectedBalls.map((ball) => {
    clonedTotalBalls.splice(ball, 1);
  })
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done like this

```
clonedTotalBalls = totalBalls.filter((element)=>!selectedBalls.includes(element))
```

The `filter` function takes a predicate that is run once on every element and returns a boolean value for each. In this case the predicate is whether or not the element is included in the `selectedBalls` array. Therefore, all elements which are included in the `selectedBalls` array will return false, while all other elements return true. `filter` also does not modify the original array, but instead creates a new one.

Comment: Thank you! this worked too. I chose to pick this as the right answer because it showed me I don't have to clone the original array.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a much better answer!

Comment: @KaiSalmon your answer solved my problem, this answer brings another solution. All the same. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

`splice` removes an element *at a particular index*, not by a particular value. 
To achieve your desired result you should use:

```
function generateNewBalls() {
  let clonedTotalBalls = [...totalBalls];

  selectedBalls.map((ball) => {
    let indexToRemove = clonedTotalBalls.indexOf(ball)
    clonedTotalBalls.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
  })
}
```

(I also recommend you change the `map` to `forEach` which is best practise if your don't want to return a value, or look into using `filter` and `indexOf`. But that isn't really relevant to your question)