# JSON-server. Filter by nested value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-server

I have DB (use json-server) like this:

```
DB = {
  products: [
    {id: 0, name: 'aaa', price: 10},
    {id: 1, name: 'bbb', price: 20},
    {id: 2, name: 'ccc', price: 50},
    {id: 3, name: 'ddd', price: 1}
  ]
};
```

And array of ids:

```
cartItemsIds: [0, 3];
```

How can I get array of objects from DB with ids from cartItemsIds ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: Not exactly. This method should be work, but I know that json-server has inline filter feature. So there's no need to load all db.products, but filter them on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. If anyone needs:

```
`products?id=${cartItemsIds.join('&id=')}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your products from db like so:

```
for(const product of DB.products) {    
  if(cartItemsIds.includes(product.id)) {
   console.log(product);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to get all DB.products and then filter them, but I want to filter them on server side at first and then get filtered array of objects.

Comment: my bad. I took a fast look to the docs. have you tried doing something like `/products/id_like=${carItemsIds}`?

Comment: or `/products/id_like=${carItemsIds.join(',')}`?

Comment: It needs to right request, request that you propose doesn't work even if carItemsIds contains only one element. But thanks for answer:)