# Filter array of objects with array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

Have an array of objects

```
var objArray = [{name: orange, id: 1},{name : apple, id:2},{name: banana, id:3},{name: grapes, id:4}]
```

and an array of id's

```
var arrId = [1,4]
```

How can i filter to get corresponding object of matching id from array of objects?

Expected:

```
var result = [{name: orange, id: 1}, {name: grapes, id:4}]
```

Tried:

```
objArray.filter(o => o.id === arrId);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var objArray = [{ name: 'orange', id: 1 }, { name: 'apple', id: 2 }, { name: 'banana', id: 3 }, { name: 'grapes', id: 4 }],
    arrId = [1, 4],
    result = objArray.filter(o => arrId.includes(o.id));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```