# How to filter an arrayof objects from all elements of another array of object on values of a common property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose to have an array of objects, as for example:

```
var arr1 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),NO:2},{t:new Date('2020-09-14'),NO2:20}];
var arr2 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),CO:2}];
```

I want to filter elements of arr1 using elements of arr2 such that to exclude that with the same values of t.
I saw a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array), but for simple arrays, where someone suggested to use `includes`.
I wonder if it is possible to use a similar approach.
I tried:

```js
var arr1 = [{
    t: new Date('2020-09-12'),
    NO: 2
  }, {
    t: new Date('2020-09-14'),
    NO2: 20
  }],
  arr2 = [{
    t: new Date('2020-09-12'),
    CO: 2
  }],
  res = arr1.filter(f => !arr2.includes(f.t));
console.log(res);
```

But it does not work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the `arr2` into array of time and use that to exclude time from `arr1` using `includes`

```js
const arr1 = [
  { t: new Date("2020-09-12"), NO: 2 },
  { t: new Date("2020-09-14"), NO2: 20 },
]
const arr2 = [{ t: new Date("2020-09-12"), CO: 2 }]

const res = arr1.filter(
  ({ t }) => !arr2.map(({ t }) => t.getTime()).includes(t.getTime())
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter simply to get result.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    t: new Date('2020-09-12'),
    NO: 2
  }, {
    t: new Date('2020-09-14'),
    NO2: 20
  }],
  arr2 = [{
    t: new Date('2020-09-12'),
    CO: 2
  }],
  res = arr1.filter(f => arr2.filter(time => time.t.getTime() != f.t.getTime()).length);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on what you have if you want to use include you need to have a simpler array or use a different function like some to check if that value exists in any of the objects in the array.

```
var arr1 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),NO:2},{t:new Date('2020-09-14'),NO2:20}],
var filterDates = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),CO:2}].map(v=>v.t),
res = arr1.filter(f => !filterDates.includes(f.t));
```

or

```
var arr1 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),NO:2},{t:new Date('2020-09-14'),NO2:20}],
res = arr1.filter(f => !arr2.some(v=>v.t===f.t));
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution is very concise, but work correctly only using .getTime for date as:  `res = arr1.filter(f => !arr2.some(v=>v.t.getTime()===f.t.getTime()));` Same hold true, actually, for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array.filter property of arrays to filter out non similar objects using the t key as check
Eg here ::

```
var arr1 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),NO:2},{t:new Date('2020-09-14'),NO2:20}]; 
var arr2 = [{t:new Date('2020-09-12'),CO:2}];

const uniqueElementsArray = arr1.filter(element => {
  // Checking if an element in arr1 is also in arr2
  let isDuplicate = arr2.some(e => e.t.getTime() === element.t.getTime())
  return !isDuplicate
})

console.log(uniqueElementsArray)
 // Would return the array below
 // [ { t: 2020-09-14T00:00:00.000Z, NO2: 20 } ]
```

The **Array.some METHOD** checks whether at least one of the elements in arr2 has the same time (**t**) as the current element of Arr1 that **Array.filter** is currently on.
Read more on Array.some [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

**t.getTime()** was used to convert the date (**t**) of an element to ***milliseconds*** to make compare the dates