# Remove object in array

Tags: reactjs

I have a array object and a array.

```
const arr1=[
    { name: "viet" },
    { name: "hai" },
    { name: "han" }
    ]
const arr2= ["viet", "hai"];
```

How can i compare and set arr like:

```
arr = [{name: "han"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :D

```
const arr1=[
    { name: "viet" },
    { name: "hai" },
    { name: "han" }
    ]
const arr2= ["viet", "hai"];
const result = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item.name))

console.log(result) // [{name: "han"}]
```

Comment: this's working, thank u so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr1=[
    { name: "viet" },
    { name: "hai" },
    { name: "han" }
    ]
const arr2= ["viet", "hai"];
let res = arr1.filter(function (n) {
                    return !this.has(n.name);
                }, new Set(arr2));
                
console.log(res);
```