# How to filter two arrays?

Tags: javascript

How to filter two arrays?

I have two arrays where allBrands are all brands and userBrands are brands that the user has already selected, I'm trying to filter allBrands in such a way that it doesn't show the brands already selected by the user

```
  const allBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "bmw" },
    { id: 2, title: "mercedes" },
    { id: 3, title: "samsung" }
  ];
  const userBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "mercedes" }
  ];

  const filtered = allBrands.filter(({ title }) => {
    return userBrands.map((item) => item.title !== title);
  }); // need bmw, samsung
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `find` inside the `filter` instead of `map` to find if the brand is already selected by the user. If brand is found in `userBrands` then return false, else return true inside filter.

```js
const allBrands = [
  { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
  { id: 1, title: "bmw" },
  { id: 2, title: "mercedes" },
  { id: 3, title: "samsung" }
];
const userBrands = [
  { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
  { id: 1, title: "mercedes" }
];

const filtered = allBrands.filter(({ title }) => {
  return !userBrands.find((item) => item.title === title);
}); // need bmw, samsung

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const allBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "bmw" },
    { id: 2, title: "mercedes" },
    { id: 3, title: "samsung" }
  ];
  const userBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "mercedes" }
  ];

  
  
  const filtered = allBrands.filter(({ title:title1 }) => !userBrands.some(({ title:title2 }) => title1 === title2));
  
  console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of filtering the allBrands Array so that it does not contain the brands already selected by the user. You can try making 2 for loops and nesting one in the other and cycling through the allBrands array to check if it contains the brand already selected by the user.
Example:

```js
const allBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "bmw" },
    { id: 2, title: "mercedes" },
    { id: 3, title: "samsung" }
  ];
  const userBrands = [
    { id: 0, title: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, title: "mercedes" }
  ];
 
 //Filtering Part
 for(let i = 0; i < allBrands.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < userBrands.length; j++) {
    if(allBrands[i] === userBrands[j]) {
        allBrands.slice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```