# js object nested array filter based on array

Tags: javascript

```
const cars = [
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: (3) ['2022/05/28', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
    },
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: (3) ['2022/05/30', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
    },
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: (3) ['2022/05/28', '2022/06/01', '2022/06/05']
    }
]
```

I want to filter my object array based on another array

```
const arr2 = ["2022/06/02", "2022/06/05"];
```

I want to get results like that;

```
[
   {
     brand: "Chevrolet",
     model: "Camaro",
     dates: (3) ['2022/05/28', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
   },
   {
     brand: "Chevrolet",
     model: "Camaro",
     dates: (3) ['2022/05/30', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
   }
]
```

I used includes

```
let filtered = cars.filter((item) => item.dates.includes(arr2))
```

I got empty array.

when I pass a string to in includes I got filtered array.

```
let filtered = cars.filter((item) => item.dates.includes("2022/06/02"))
```

No I need to compare **arr2**. Its' length could be changed.

How can I pass an array to `cars.include()` function

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to compare an array [arr2] to a string. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: Since the filte (`arr2`) is an array: you want the `dates` to include BOTH, or that include AT LEAST ONE of them ? By your expected result, looks like BOTH, but just asking for assurance.

Comment: by the way.. since your problem is mainly how to check if an array contains any value from another array, you should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript ... array.includes expects a single value as argument to look for in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
[{}, {}].includes({})
```

returns `false` because it compares objects by object reference, not values in the object, so it's equivalent to

```
const a = {}; // new, empty object
const b = {}; // a different new, empty object
const c = {}; // yet another new, empty object
const answer = [a, b].includes(c) // false
```

Also, arrays are objects!

So that's why, when you pass an object (whether or not it's an array) into Array.prototype.includes, it returns `false` unless that same object is an element of the array.

You probably want something like this:

```
// Function that returns true if two arrays intersect
const includesAny = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.some(e1 => arr2.includes(e1));

const filterCarsByDates = (
  datesSought => cars.filter(
    car => includesAny(
      cars.dates,
      datesSought
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: It works. No I dont want to any. Has to be all arr2 values in objects dates array.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it like that and it worked                                                                   loadedCars.filter((car) => !includesAny(car.dates, datesSought));

Comment: For all, change `some` to `every`

Comment: One more question. How can I update React State when I filtered object array? When I filtered just one time and I lost my first data

Comment: I don't know React.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cars = [
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: ['2022/05/28', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
    },
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: ['2022/05/30', '2022/06/02', '2022/06/05']
    },
    {
        brand: "Chevrolet",
        model: "Camaro",
        dates: ['2022/05/28', '2022/06/01', '2022/06/05']
    }
];
    
let arr2 = ["2022/06/02", "2022/06/05"];

// A method that checks if `src` array contains all elements of `target` array
let checker = (src, target) => target.every(v => src.includes(v));  

let filtered = cars.filter((item) => checker(item.dates, arr2));  

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array Filter with Set, Searching in Set is faster than Array.

```js
const cars = [
  {
    brand: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Camaro",
    dates: ["2022/05/28", "2022/06/02", "2022/06/05"],
  },
  {
    brand: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Camaro",
    dates: ["2022/05/30", "2022/06/02", "2022/06/05"],
  },
  {
    brand: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Camaro",
    dates: ["2022/05/28", "2022/06/01", "2022/06/05"],
  },
];

const arr2 = ["2022/06/02", "2022/06/05"];

const result = cars.filter((car) => {
  const set = new Set(car.dates);
  return arr2.every((date) => set.has(date));
});

console.log(result);
```