# filter json object with an array and return a new json with matching values of array

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

```
    var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                          { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]

    var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]
```

I want to filter out the json object with values matching with an array and return a new json object. I tried the below, but does not seem to work.

Expected Output:

```
Expected : [
  { name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
  { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
  { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }
]
```

Below Code doesnt seem to work:

```
var newArray = [];
structureInfos.forEach(function(structureInfos) {
   for (let i=0; i < structureElements.length; i++){
        if(structureElements[i] === structureInfos[i]['name']){
           newArray.push(structureInfos[i]);
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: `structureInfos.filter(e => structureElements.includes(e.name))`

Comment: `const structureElements = new Set([ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]); structureInfos.filter(info => structureElements.has(info.name));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one liner solution using ES6 arrow function:

```js
const filteredArray = structureInfos.filter(info => structureElements.includes(info.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your code that probably explain why it isn't working for you.

```js
var newArray = [];
structureInfos.forEach(function(structureInfos) {
  for (let i = 0; i < structureElements.length; i++) {
    if (structureElements[i] === structureInfos[i]['name']) {
      newArray.push(structureInfos[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

It looks like you are iterating through your structureElements array inside your forEach(), but then you are using the same index identifier "i" when referencing structureInfos. With the forEach function the first argument in the callback is the current element of the array, so this should work better for you:

```js
var newArray = [];
structureInfos.forEach(function(structureInfo) { // Gave it a different name than the input array
  for (let i = 0; i < structureElements.length; i++) {
    if (structureElements[i] === structureInfo['name']) { // Removed the index identifier
      newArray.push(structureInfo); // Pushing the current record
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: don't use same name of array as paramenter in foreach callback.. for more clarification check below answer 5th method

Comment: I didn't use same name of array as parameter, I was pointing out that the asker did that. My parameter is the singular form of the original plural name which is different. Hence why my code works.

Answer (score -1):

1st Method using map or filter

```js
var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                          { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]

    var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]
    
let newStructureInfos =     structureElements.map((ele)=>{
return structureInfos.filter((item)=>item.name === ele)
}).flat();
console.log(newStructureInfos)
```

2nd Method filter or includes

```js
  var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                              { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                              { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                              { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]

var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]

let newinfo = structureInfos.filter((item)=> structureElements.includes(item.name))
console.log(newinfo)
```

3rd Method loop or spread operator

```js
var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                          { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]
var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]

let newInfo = [];
for(let item of structureInfos){
  if(structureElements.includes(item.name)){
    newInfo = [...newInfo,item]
  }
}
console.log(newInfo);
```

4th method using loops

```js
var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                          { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]

var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]

let Info = []
for(let stinfo of structureInfos){
    for(let stele of structureElements){
        if(stinfo.name === stele){
          Info.push(stinfo);
          break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(Info)
```

5th method using foeach

```js
var structureInfos = [{ name: 'HMDB0006285', identifier: 'Six two eight 5' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006288', identifier: 'Six two double eight'},
                          { name: 'HMDB0006293', identifier: 'Six two nine three' },
                          { name: 'HMDB0006294', identifier: 'Six two Nine Four' }]

    var structureElements = [ 'HMDB0006285', 'HMDB0006293', 'HMDB0006294' ]
    
let newInfo = [];
structureInfos.forEach((element)=>{
  for(let i=0; i<structureElements.length; i++){
    if(element.name === structureElements[i]){
       newInfo.push(element);
       break;
    }
  }
})
console.log(newInfo)
```