# Filter the array with another array containing the names to be filtered from the first array

Tags: javascript

```
input : ['Ram', 'Shyam' , 'Hari' , 'Gopal' , 'Hawa'] 
['Shyam' , 'Hawa']

output: ['Ram' , 'Hari' , 'Gopal']
```

Comment: use inexof ......

Comment: What have you done so far..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.filter() array using another array's elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements)

Comment: ES6 takes care of this stuff nicely with Sets (creating union, diff, intersects is nice and terse).

http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I update to your values in array:

"To me it seems like you're making it a little too complicated.

Iterating three times (filter, for loop, for in loop).
Using a for in loop for an array.
Using both new Array and [...]."

```
 var myArray = [['Ram', 'Shyam' , 'Hari' , 'Gopal' , 'Hawa'], 
    ['Shyam' , 'Hawa']];

    var userPassedFilter = ["Hawa"];

    newArray = consolidatedFilters(myArray, userPassedFilter);
    console.log(newArray);

    function consolidatedFilters(passedArray, passedFilter) {
        var filteredArray = passedArray.filter(
        function(el) { // executed for each person
            for (var i = 0; i < passedFilter.length; i++) { // iterate over filter
                if (el[1].indexOf(passedFilter[i]) != -1) {
                    return true; // if this person knows this language
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        );     
    return filteredArray;
}
```

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements)

Comment: actually i want to remove 'Shyam' and 'Hari' from my input. The above code helps me but i am not getting desired output.

Comment: You can put what you want (output) in the line: var userPassedFilter = ["xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx"];

Comment: and in line 2 ['xxxx' , 'xxxx', 'xxxx' ]];