# Filtering an array but Item is being skipped

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, array-splice

I am trying to filter an array using the following method however, I have one value that is being skipped!

```html
function filterArray(array,remove){
    
    console.log('Array Length:',array.length)
    console.log("Array:",array);
    console.log('Remove:',remove);
    console.log('------');
    array.forEach(function(e){       
       if(remove.includes(e.serial)){
           console.log('remove this item:',e);
           array.splice(array.indexOf(e),1);
       }       
    });
    
    console.log('New Array Length:',array.length);
    return array;
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Would someone please shed some light on this situation?

Here is a my console output

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `array.filter`?

Comment: if you remove the current array element using splice, then the `next` element becomes the current element, and the last thing that happens after your forEach callback function is called is the current index is incremented, therefore you skip what was the next element

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - `array.splice` mutates array in place, `array.filter` returns a new array - this may not be the intent of the code

Comment: Potentially, but the function returns an array, so you would imagine the intent is not necessarily to mutate it in place.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli perhaps the in place mutation is unknown to the OP :p

Comment: by the way - forEach call back accepts more than one argument, the second being the current index - so `array.splice(array.indexOf(e)` could be greatly simplified

Comment: hint: sometimes a `for loop` is a better tool for the job than .forEach/.map/.filter/.etc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to mutate the original array, you can use filter:

```
function filterArray(array, remove){
    return array.filter(e => !remove.includes(e.serial));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Filtering the array turned out to be the best option. I came across this solution and it worked out pretty good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements