# How do I only pull certain data from an API field?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a React app that displays a list of all 195 of the current countries, according to this [list](https://www.worldometers.info/geography/how-many-countries-are-there-in-the-world/). However, the [api](https://restcountries.eu/#rest-countries) that I am trying to pull from lists some 249 countries. Is there a way to only display the 195 current countries?

I am new to this, and I have tried searching for a solution, but I'm afraid I might be phrasing this question incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

So, it might not be the "best" solution, but you can use array.prototype.slice().

You can slice the list from where you want up to where you don't want the list, and the slice will return a new array (not modifying the original).

```
let url = 'yourcountrythingy.com';
const get190somethingCountries = async () => {
 let response = await fetch(url);
 let data = await response.json();
 let newData = data.slice(0, 191); // you'll get an array of countries from the first index (0) until the 191st index
 return newData;
}

// ... do something with that newData
```

I didn't really look at the api, so might have to adjust the fetch code, but the slice() should work. Here's also the docs from mdn.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: plus, if you wanted to add Taiwan in there (or any countries you want added in the list that isn't recognized globally), you can use splice(). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: You can just edit your post, you don't need to add a comment. The little "edit" button is directly underneath your content and to the left of your avatar. :)

Comment: I don't think OP wants a list of ANY 191 countries. They want the same countries shown on worldometers.info and only those.

Comment: oops. 
for filtering the two arrays, here's a different question that can help you out using filter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353917/filter-array-using-another-arrays-elements

Comment: Okay, so after a little digging, I realized that the api was providing me with all 249 countries, areas, and territories according to the [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) standard. That worked for for me. However, I'll try to solve the original problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add a 'limit' parameter in the API's URL, like so:
`https://api-website.com/countries?limit=195`